# How to get click event on body except one section

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have designing page like

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="head">
        <img src="images/menuI.png" />
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Normally Ul will be hidden

```
#head ul{
display:none;
}
```

In Js

```
 $('#head img').on('click', function(e){
        $('#head ul').toggle();
    });
```

Here My question is

If i click on body, head ul have to to be hidden other than head and head ul.

That is When i click on body, That UL tabe will be hide. But body tags has #head Ul also. I have trying by using z-index. but it is not working for me

And second question is.

Not consider above situation

When i click on ul tag, It have to show and If i click on li tag, It have to be hide.

Comment: Your Question is unclear. Do you want to show the <ul> part on click of the img ?

Comment: Yes. when i click on img, UL will be show. When i click on body(other than that img), it will be hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#head img, #head li').on('click', function(e){
        $('#head ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
 });
 $(document).not("#head").on('click', function(e){
    $('#head ul').hide();
 });
```

Comment: can't get it, what type of problems/issues you see with this code? Please metion more to understand.

Comment: Well for starters, the UL hides when clicked upon if you write it like this.

Comment: Before i used toggle. Now i changed to hide. So its working Now. and i have one more scenario like that. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Just as demonstration, all works correct for me, check the snippet below:

```js
 $('#head img').on('click', function(e){
        $('#head ul').toggle();
    });
```

```css
#head ul{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="head">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200x50" />
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```